VB Net Debug in Visual Studio 2022 is case-sensitive
I have a strange problem with Visual Studio 2022 and VB.Net. The same problem does not occur with Visual Studio 2019
I opened an old project and it seems that debugging is case-sensitive
For example, if in debug I execute this statement
Dim test As String = "Hello"

Then I go to the debug window and write
?test

Obviously the result is ‘Hello’ in both VS2002 and VS2019
But if I write
?TEST

In VS2019 I get ‘Hello’ while in VS2022 I get the error ‘Unable to resolve identifier: 'Test’
What could this behaviour be due to?

MS probably changed this behaviour to align with other languages, such as C# which is case sensitive.

For the record, you couldn't debug that statement because it's not valid. A String is delimited by double-quotes, not single.

Works fine when I try it, VS2022 version 17.9.3.  Use Help > About to see your version, use Help > Send Feedback to file a bug.

@jmcilhinney sorry for the error. Obviously in the actual code I used double-quotes

@HansPassant my versione is 17.8.0. I'll try to update

I updated VS2022 to version 17.9.3 and now all works as expected.
The Debug Windows is now case-insensitive and if i try to print the value of a non declared variable I got the familiar "Error BC30451 'xxxxxxx' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"
